# Relation between Class (Type) & IBOutlet for Interface Builder Views

Tags: class, interface-builder, iboutlet

I just want to confirm that I'm understanding correctly, in Interface Builder the Class set under Class Identity (listed under Type in the name.xib summary window) is the class of the view whereas in IBOutlet Class *viewName the class listed describes the nature of the connection to Interface Builder, is this correct?

e.g.

Name__________________________________Type

File's Owner_______________________SomeViewController

First Responder____________________UIResponder

MyLabel____________________________UILabel
.

IBOutlet UILabel *lblMyLabel

UILabel is the class of the label and IBOutlet UILabel is the type of connection between the code and the IB object, right?

I ask because I subclassed UIImageView & updated the view's class but left the IBOutlet declaration as IBOutlet UIImageView and it still works so I assume the IBOutlet part is just a description or a guideline.

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is, why does my swipeable image only work when I set it's class to my SwipeableImageView class but leave the interface builder var as IBOutlet UIImageView *mySwipeableImageView, surely the interface builder connection should also be set as IBOutlet SwipeableImage *mySwipeableImageView ?

Comment: Never mind, turns out it was an IB issue, next time I booted the machine all worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are speaking about the IBOutlet keyword that you put in the @interface part of the class like this:

```
@interface Myclass {
  IBOutlet SomeOtherClass *myObj;
}
```

, this tells Interface Builder that you will use this class member to connect to o a "SomeOtherClass" object in Interface Builder. After you write this member, you will be able to drag a connection from this object to a "SomeOtherClass" object in interface builder and select the "myObj" outlet, and when the .nib will be read at runtime, you will have both the objects and the connection between them available. 
The "UILabel" that you mentioned is indeed the class of the object.